# How can answers tend to be opinions if there are no answers?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, reopen-closed, opinion-based

I recently posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29778763/what-technical-things-can-be-done-with-pdf-but-not-an-html-website?noredirect=1#comment47689859_29778763) that was "put on hold as primarily opinion-based". In the explanation it says (emphasis mine):

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but **answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions**, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

But my question had ***no answers yet***. How can reviewers be asked to predict what "will tend to be"? As far as I can tell the question was not worded in a way to ask for opinions, and I even tried to clarify it to specifically ask for fact-based answers, despite the closers not providing any reasoning for their close option.

Should the explanation for "put on hold as primarily opinion-based" be changed so that a question can only be closed when it actually gets some opinion-based answers? Or should this close-reason be disabled until there is at least 1 answer?

---

**Edit**: My recommendation is that the wording for this close-reason be changed to be based on the contents of the question & answers rather than what "will tend to be".

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question ***are*** almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise; ***or the question is specifically asking for opinions***.

Comment: You are missing the key phrase.... `will tend to be`.... the point is questions of a specific nature attract questions that are only opinions, and/or it is very difficult to answer with anything else other than an opinion.

Comment: Meh. So if it's not a pure-bred opinion question, it's a list question. It should be closed either way, little point arguing over the exactly correct reason.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - There are certainly ways to answer this question with facts. Someone wrote a few comments with wonderful factual answers but they were deleted for some reason. The fact is that *no one provided an opinionated answer*... so I'm still confused what it was about the question that made it seem "opinionated".

Comment: "little point arguing over the exactly correct reason" I respectfully disagree with this. If it doesn't matter what people choose when closing a question, why bother having a choice? If it's a "list question" and that's bad, I would like to know so I can improve the quality of my questions.

Comment: Downvoters: Please provide some comments to help improve the question... or an answer.

Comment: The answers are the answers and will always be the answers.

Answer (score 12):

> Which things can be done with A but not with B?

This is not a good question for Stack Overflow. The kind of questions that make SO the great resource it is, are questions like:

- How can I do X with A?
- Why can't I do X with A?
- How can I do X with A, which I do like Y with B?

Those are tightly-scoped questions that can be answered with facts and links to resources proving those facts. There is a finite number of answers to them, of which the quality can be controlled.

Now the question *"What are the differences between A and B?"* can lead to a plethora of answers. Some of them are false, others were true but are now outdated, some of them are opinion-based and as such the page containing the question and answers is worth nothing, as the visitor isn't very likely to find the answer to the question they were researching.

I mean, just about the "secure offline" part of the question, or *"How can you implement a PDF-like DRM for web applications"* you could write a couple of books.

That being said, the proper close reason would be "too broad": too many possible answers, and the answers you do ask for would be too long for SO.

Comment: Thank you. "Too broad" is probably the correct reasoning for closing that question. But this does not answer: *How can reviewers be asked to predict what "will tend to be"?* Seems like closing an "opinionated" question is itself very opinionated.

Comment: @Luke there's a fine line between "too broad" and "opinion-based". _"How would you..."_-questions are both, but more the latter. Your question was more of the former.