# My question was deleted for being opinion based even though I indicated replies should be fact-based

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, closed-questions

### UPDATE 2:

I want to thank everyone who provided feedback. It has been very helpful, especially the links to where the duplicates are. I tell you, I searched already and I'm known for being a great researcher, and I did not find any duplicates. You guys must be magicians! ... But, I digress ...

Even though I believe there is a good discussion that can come from this information, I can see why the community believes that this doesn't adhere to the posting guidelines for StackOverflow, despite my best efforts, and I'm a little bitter over it (though I suppose some may see it as putting lipstick on a pig). But, like I say, I realize everyone is just trying to help, which I appreciate very much.

So, In the interest of good community participation, I am willing to defer to the community. ***What should I do now?*** Should I delete my question or leave it up for posterity, or something else?

Thanks!

### UPDATE 1:

*Maybe I can clarify my post. In my mind it's not an opinion piece, but people are assuming it is let me give you an example. If I asked "Did King Arthur really exist?" I would expect all kinds of answers. However, the ones that would be "thumbs upped" would be those stating facts: "No one knows for sure, but researcher a and her team discover blank artifact in north Scotland which mentions the name "Artur", and there are tales of "Outeur the King" in ancient gaelic scrolls from monks found in france." Etc... hope that makes sense.*

---

### ORIGINAL:

This is a link to my question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287600/whats-wrong-with-w3schools-and-why-should-they-be-avoided

I read the posting guidelines for StackOverflow already, which is why I anticipated that this might generate a bunch of opinions if I didn't pre-clarify the purpose. So, ***before I even posted*** I took the extra effort and wrote in there that answers were to be fact-based and evidence-based.

I already solved the issue of "appropriateness", right? So, why was my post deleted, and what is wrong (if anything) with my logic?

Thanks.

P.S.: I flagged an administrator with my concerns within 5 minutes of seeing negative votes, but as yet have not had the benefit of a response.

Comment: The question is a poll - you are asking people to share their experience. Can you explain how you would objectively choose the *correct/best* answer from all the ones you would have potentially gotten?

Comment: Stating you want only facts doesn't change the fact that the only answers it could receive are opinions related to whether or not statistic A is good or bad.

Comment: As for why you have not received a response yet - the moderator queue on Stack Overflow is standing at ~1,600 flags at this time. Do you really expect immediate responses from moderators?

Comment: @Oded Ok, I guess I see what you are saying. In answer to question though, I would choose -- much as is often the case on the English Language SE -- the answer with the most examples, and the most details. A great answer would something like "Hi, I used to work for W3Schools and -blank- is why people used to bad-mouth us, but -blank2- is what we did to improve it."

Comment: Changed the tags - do not use the "bug" tag in this manner - I suggest you read the tag description before you use it next.

Comment: [Very similar question here on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280478/1990216) at least from the pov of posting on SO (based on your title at least, I didn't/can't see the question)

Comment: Problem here - SO is not ELL - it has a lot less tolerance to such questions.

Comment: @Oded Thanks for changing the tags. I was required to post 5 tags and none of them fit, so I just picked one. Also, I had no idea the moderators were so busy. The few times I've flagged them in the past, I got quick response. I guess I don't really understand `exactly` how moderation works, but I do appreciate there must be a lot of work involved.

Comment: @EricHepperle-CodeSlayer2010:  You're *never* required to enter 5 tags.  You're only required to enter either discussion, feature-request or bug on Meta, but not 5.

Comment: Closely related: [How can answers tend to be opinions if there are no answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291012)

Comment: Also, note that the downvotes/negative votes on this meta post are because people disagree with you, not because there's something wrong with it.

Comment: "I flagged an administrator with my concerns within 5 minutes of seeing negative votes, but as yet have not had the benefit of a response." - What do you expect the response to be.  The administrators cannot reverse the votes. The votes were issued in good faith.  Your question was deleted for a valid reason.  At the end of the day if enough people vote to delete your question it's deleted.

Answer (score 14):

Here's what I see:  you're asking a question about why a third-party website should (or should not) be trusted.

This comes across to me as opinionated at a minimum, since people will draw their own conclusions about a resource with some hint of bias (W3Schools being one of those "notorious" sites).

The deletion was probably warranted because three people believed that, no matter the amount of editing you could do, you couldn't change it into something else that would be on topic; an edit to take the focus *away* from W3Schools would be asking for resources at best.

Comment: Regardless, it's off-topic for SO as it's not asking a practical, answerable **programming** question.

Comment: @Paulie_D:  There are questions on SO about IDE configuration, which aren't programming questions, but is *related* to programming.  So that's not the reason why it's off-topic; this question is just looking for an opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Maybe I can clarify my post. In my mind it's not an opinion piece, but people are assuming it is let me give you an example.

If I asked "Did King Arthur really exist?" I would expect all kinds of answers. However, the ones that would be "thumbs upped" would be those stating facts: "No one knows for sure, but researcher a and her team discover _blank_ artifact in north Scotland which mentions the name "Artur", and there are tales of "Outeur the King" in ancient gaelic scrolls from monks found in france." Etc... hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Makoto questions related to tools used for programming are on topic. I'm not entirely sure if documentation is considered a tool.

Comment: @EricHepperle-CodeSlayer2010 At the end of the day, "did King Arthur really exist" is a question with an objectively correct answer.  Nobody may ever know what it is, and we may be forced to live with an educated guess based on analyzing various forms of evidence, but even so, there *is* an objectively correct answer one way or another.  "Is this site a good site" has no objectively correct answer.  It can only ever be answered with a person's opinion, which can never be correct or incorrect.  Questions like that aren't appropriate on SO.